Understanding Detached Entities and Garbage Collection in Hibernate - closed
I'm a beginner studying Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA, and I have a few questions regarding detached entities and memory management.
I learned that when an entity is detached, it is no longer managed by the persistence context. Additionally, I understand that just calling flush() or clear() on the persistence context doesn’t necessarily mean that the detached object is immediately removed from memory.
According to the Hibernate documentation, the detach() and clear() methods are meant to remove entities from the first-level cache, making them eligible for garbage collection. However, it seems contradictory because once the entity is in the Detached state, the reference between the entity and Hibernate is severed.
in Hibernate doc - 7.13. Session cache management (hibernate)

Session cache management - Entity instances aren’t automatically evicted from the session cache when they’re no longer needed. Instead, they stay pinned in memory until the session they belong to is discarded by your program. The methods detach() and clear() allow you to remove entities from the session cache, making them available for garbage collection. Since most sessions are rather short-lived, you won’t need these operations very often. And if you find yourself thinking you do need them in a certain situation, you should strongly consider an alternative solution: a stateless session.

in Red Hat doc - 10.1. Hibernate object states (redhat)

Detached - a detached instance is an object that has been persistent, but its Session has been closed. The reference to the object is still valid, of course, and the detached instance might even be modified in this state. A detached instance can be reattached to a new Session at a later point in time, making it (and all the modifications) persistent again. This feature enables a programming model for long running units of work that require user think-time. We call them application transactions, i.e., a unit of work from the point of view of the user.

Here are my questions:
After an entity becomes detached and is no longer managed by the persistence context, where exactly is the detached object stored until it's referenced again?
If the reference is broken between Hibernate and the detached entity, how does calling clear() on the session cache ensure that the detached entity is eligible for garbage collection?
Could you please clarify this process and, if possible, provide some references or links to relevant documentation?
Thank you for your time and guidance!

Detached has nothing to do with garbage collection, so don't get them too tied together. The docs you link are from different times. Clear/Detach are JPA concepts, but are based on older Hibernate logic which is referred to in your second link. Detaching something means it is no longer managed (or tied to a session anymore in Hibernate). Hibernate native api had a way to reattach an entity to a session to get any changes you might have made to be picked up - this seems similar to calling Entitymanager merge in JPA. Nothing is storing a detached entity - it is up to your app

Thank you for your comment. As you mentioned, it can be confirmed from the official Hibernate documentation that the Hibernate API session is extended from JPA’s EntityManager. Even when the session (JPA - EntityManager) is closed, a detached object can be reattached through the Hibernate API.
The merge function, as its name suggests, only copies the detached object, and the memory of the detached object still persists.

@Chris
According to GPT, the detached object remains in the JVM heap memory in a POJO state. However, no matter how much I search for a source on this, I cannot find any documentation supporting this claim.
When exactly does the detached object get destroyed? In other words, when does the garbage collection track and remove it? If there is a source, I would appreciate it if you could share it. That’s what I’m curious about. Thank you.

When does any java object get destroyed? As the docs you've already linked state, detached means your JPA provider has nothing to do with it, no links to it. It is just an object. It will, like any java object, only get cleaned up by GC when gc runs and there is nothing referencing it in the applicaton anymore. do you have a memory issue in your application? Clear/detached have nothing to do with java system GC, they only control the entity manager level cache.

Java relies on the garbage collector (GC) to free up memory. GC targets objects that are either no longer referenced or set to null. However, detached objects are not null, and their references are still intact. This is because detached objects can still be merged back into the persistence context whenever needed. My concern stems from the idea that if detached objects keep accumulating over time, wouldn't that eventually lead to an OutOfMemoryError?

I think you misinterpret what detached means. Object o = new Object();. o is just a pointer to the new Object I created. If it is a detached entity or just an Object doesn't matter, it cannot get garbage collected until my 'o' pointer is no longer referencing it. Detaching an entity means the entity, just like the new Object, still exist only your JPA provider doesn't have any references to it. It won't get garbage collected though if your application still does. If it is managed, JPA still has a reference to it, but when it is  detached, it doesn't.

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2351569
that's very long time ago, but still a valueable question for me..

Not sure your point or question - The EntityManager is required to track changes on everything read through it. A weak reference would allow the GC to clear the object (if no longer referenced in the app) and lose your changes. This is something other providers support, but usually in the second layer cache (ie at the EMF level). See EclipseLink https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/concepts/cache001.htm

@Chris Thank you so much, Chris, for patiently and sincerely answering all of my frustrating questions. I truly appreciate it :)
